# python retrieve key object from dictionary

Tags: collections, python-2.7

I have created a class that will allow me to store meta-data with an arbitrary dictionary key and still pass the `in` test with the original object type:

```
class DictKey:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.hashkey = hash(key)
        self.member = key

    def __hash__(self):
        return self.hashkey

    def __repr__(self):
        return 'DictKey(' + self.strkey + ')'

    def __cmp__(self, o):
        return cmp(self.member, o)

d = {}
key = DictKey('hello')
d[key] = 'world'

print key.hashkey
print hash('hello')
print key in d
print 'hello' in d
print DictKey('hello') in d
```

produces the output:

```
840651671246116861
840651671246116861
True
True
True
```

Now, given the string 'hello', I need to get the instance of DictKey that was created from said string in constant time:

```
if 'hello' in d:
    #need some way to return the instance of DictKey so I can get at it's member
    tmp = d.getkey('hello') 
    tmp.member
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more conventional way to store "meta" data along with a dict would be either:

1. to maintain two `dict`s with same set of keys, one for the actual data, one for "meta"
2. to have a `dict` with ("raw") keys, and values are 2-tuples: ( value, item-meta-data )

Both are simple and require no special magic.  You would also avoid problems like the one you describe in your question (and others to come).

Comment: I was trying to avoid the two-dict solution because it would be nice to not have to use that space (the dictionaries in our app can get very large). However, it looks like that's going to be the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @Hersheezy if you find this answer helpful, feel free to accept it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I've made a slight modification to your base code:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return 'DictKey(' + self.member + ')'
```

Then if you want to retrieve the instance of DictKey in the set of keys you can do the following:

```
index_of_instance = d.keys().index('hello')
my_instance_of_dict_key = d.keys()[index_of_instance]
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Both calls to keys() are O(n) I believe. I need the lookup to be constant time. Thanks though!